# Change the text of standard permissions in the Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How to change the text of the permission in the admin panel to `<select>` from:

```
inc|Modelname|Can add permissions
```

on:

`Modelname|add`

Comment: Are you looking at creating a custom permission or modifying the look and feel of an inbuilt permission

Comment: @Bhavani Ravi modifying. I want to change the appearance of these permissions in the <select> Admin Panel.

Comment: The appearance is defined by `__str__` method of permission model. I can't think of any method other than modifying django's source code

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L72

Comment: @Bhavani Ravi place the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance is defined by `__str__` method of permission model. I can't think of any method other than modifying django's source code

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L72

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hard and clumsy translate this text into your own language, then it must be done through the database manager in the tables with the names of permissions and content_type.